# python regex/split between two names in string

Tags: python, regex

I have a large string :

> Larry E Z ( 29s ) Larry E Z: Hi. Thank you for contacting TE, how may
>   I help you? ( 42s ) Cesar Mendez : Hello Larry ( 57s ) Larry E Z: Good
>   Afternoon Cesar ( 1m 3s ) Cesar Mendez : on drawing 2098753 ( 1m 12s )
>   Cesar Mendez : what does note 9 mena? ( 1m 18s ) Cesar Mendez : mean (
>   2m 4s ) Cesar Mendez : "sealing capability must be evaluated on an
>   application basis ( 2m 6s ) Larry E Z: The 9 does not have a specific
>   meaning. ( 2m 32s ) Cesar Mendez : this
>   sentence................."sealing capability must be evaluated on an
>   application basis" ( 3m 3s ) Larry E Z: You are meaning Note 9 ( 3m
>   14s ) Cesar Mendez : ... yes ( 3m 17s ) Larry E Z: Ok ( 3m 25s )

I need to split the string into two different list - one with everything Larry E Z said and one with Cesar Mendez . Is there a way ?

Comment: Are there line breaks here? Have you tried splitting simply on colons?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  The Python docs are pretty good and there are a number of good online regex tutorials. There are also a few good python flavoredonline regex testers to help you build your patterns - like regex101.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regular expression, you can grab all of them.

```
import re

# input text
text="""Larry E Z ( 29s ) Larry E Z: Hi. Thank you for contacting TE, how may I help you? ( 42s ) Cesar Mendez : Hello Larry ( 57s ) Larry E Z: Good Afternoon Cesar ( 1m 3s ) Cesar Mendez : on drawing 2098753 ( 1m 12s ) Cesar Mendez : what does note 9 mena? ( 1m 18s ) Cesar Mendez : mean ( 2m 4s ) Cesar Mendez : "sealing capability must be evaluated on an application basis ( 2m 6s ) Larry E Z: The 9 does not have a specific meaning. ( 2m 32s ) Cesar Mendez : this sentence................."sealing capability must be evaluated on an application basis" ( 3m 3s ) Larry E Z: You are meaning Note 9 ( 3m 14s ) Cesar Mendez : ... yes ( 3m 17s ) Larry E Z: Ok ( 3m 25s )"""

# regex for Larry
patt1 = re.compile('Larry E Z:(.*?)\(')
larry = patt1.findall(text)  # get all Larry's part as list
print(larry)

# regex for Cesar
patt2 = re.compile('Cesar Mendez :(.*?)\(')
cesar = patt2.findall(text)  # get all Cesar's
print(cesar)
```

The output:

[' Hi. Thank you for contacting TE, how may I help you? ', ' Good Afternoon Cesar ', ' The 9 does not have a specific meaning. ', ' You are meaning Note 9 ', ' Ok ']

[' Hello Larry ', ' on drawing 2098753 ', ' what does note 9 mena? ', ' mean ', ' "sealing capability must be evaluated on an application basis ', ' this sentence................."sealing capability must be evaluated on an application basis" ', ' ... yes ']

Answer (score 0):

This won't break it out into list by person but it will create named capture groups, one being the name. From there you can loop through the results and make a list. Hope this helps, there might be a way to do it all in regex but I can't figure it out at the moment.

```
(?<Person>Cesar Mendez|Larry E Z)[: ]{0,3}(?<text>.*?) ?\( ?(?<Time>.*?) ?\)
```